# Draggable element out of cursor on scaled container

Tags: css, reactjs, resize, scale

I am new React.I am working on a project which has features like:drag,drop,scroll,zoom-in,zoom-out.
The draggable components are dragged from its container say **containerA**  and dropped into another container say **containerB** . ContainerA has the feature of zoom-in and zoom-out.I have implemented zoom-in and zoom-out by changing the scale value of the container accordingly.

On Drop of component onto the container with higher scale value,the scale of component is automatically set  relative to the scale of the container.

But the problem is: **When dragging this component with scale relative to the the scale of the container it is getting back to its original size and is out of the cursor. How do i achieve the component attached to cursor and is relative to the scale of the container while dragging as well**
Help would be appreciated

```
zoomState(e) {
switch (e.deltaY > 0) {
  case true:
  if(out==0)
  {
    if(this.state.scale>2.5)
    {
    this.zoomOut(e);
    }
    }

  else{
  }
  break;
  default:

    this.zoomIn(e);

    }
  }
zoomIn = (e) => {
  this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale * 2});
    console.log("zoomin" + ""+ this.state.scale)
    e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`
    out=0  
  }
zoomOut = (e) => {
  this.setState({ scale: this.state.scale / 2});
   e.target.style.transform = `scale(${this.state.scale})`
   console.log("zoomout" + ""+ this.state.scale)
   if(this.state.scale==1)
   {
     e.target.style.transform=null
   }
  }

  dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
    var dragtarget1=document.getElementById("dragtarget1")
    var dragtarget2=document.getElementById("dragtarget2")
    if(event.target.id=="dragtarget1")
    {
     setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget1.classList.add('hide');
    });

  }
  if(event.target.id=="dragtarget2")
  {
   setTimeout(function(){
    dragtarget2.classList.add('hide');
  });
}
console.log(dragtarget1.style)
    }
    allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

    }
    drop=(event)=> {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
      event.target.appendChild(data);
      data.style.position = "fixed";

      if(this.state.scale>1){
        data.style.left = (event.nativeEvent.offsetX - data.clientWidth / 2)  + "px";
        data.style.top = (event.nativeEvent.offsetY - data.clientHeight / 2) + "px";

      }
      else{
        data.style.left = (event.clientX - data.clientWidth / 2)  + "px";
        data.style.top = (event.clientY - data.clientHeight / 2)  + "px";
        }
      var dragtarget1=document.getElementById("dragtarget1")
      setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget1.classList.remove('hide');
      });
      var dragtarget2=document.getElementById("dragtarget2")
      setTimeout(function(){
      dragtarget2.classList.remove('hide');
      });
      console.log(dragtarget1.style)

    }
    cood(){
     var bg=document.getElementById("bg")
     bg.style.transform=null
    }
    onMouseMove(e)
    {
      xcood=e.nativeEvent.offsetX
      ycood= e.nativeEvent.offsetY 
      console.log(xcood,ycood)
    }
    render() {
    return (
      <div id="base" >   
      <div className="first" id="first">

      </div>
      <div className="second">
      <div className="container">
           <div  id="bg" ref="bg"
           onWheel={(e)=>this.zoomState(e)}
           className="bg-image-wrapper"
           style={{ 'transform': `scale(${this.state.scale})`}}
           onDrop={(e)=>this.drop(e)} onDragOver={(e)=>this.allowDrop(e)} 
           //onMouseMove={(e)=>this.onMouseMove(e)}
           >

          </div> 


      </div>
      <div className="comp">

      <div className="droptarget1">
      <div 
      style={{
         height:25,
         width:25,
         backgroundColor:"red",
         position:"fixed", 
         display:"inline"
       }}
       onDragStart={(e)=>this.dragStart(e)} draggable="true" id="dragtarget1">
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="droptarget2"> 
      <div
      style={{
        height:25,
        width:25,
        backgroundColor:"blue",
        position:"fixed", 
        display:"inline"
      }}
      onDragStart={(e)=>this.dragStart(e)} draggable="true" id="dragtarget2">
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div className="third">


    </div>

    </div>   
      );
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the code snippets for what you have tried?

Comment: @AdamHinckley Above edited version has the necessary code snippet

Comment: @AdamHinckley means to say, if you can provide some fiddle or sandbox example, that would be really helpful figuring out the problem.

Comment: Note: don't use `getElementById` native api, use React refs... please bother to read https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @AdamHinckley Can i not be able to achieve it with getElementById